# How to specify recursive paths in OpenAPI / Swagger

Tags: recursion, swagger, openapi

I'd like to create a recursive specification for my Swagger API.  This concept seems to be absent from [the Swagger documentation](https://swagger.io/specification/#pathsObject), so I suspect that it's just not possible.  So I'm also open to any alternative solutions that are supported by Swagger.

For example, I'm trying to create a document-like structure.  Each document has sections, and each section has both text and its own sections.
I'm planning on having API endpoints like this:

- http://a.b.com/docs/{document-id}
- http://a.b.com/docs/{document-id}/section/{section-id}
- http://a.b.com/docs/{document-id}/section/{section-id}/section/{section-id}
- http://a.b.com/docs/{document-id}/section/{section-id}/section/{section-id}/section/{section-id}

If I were using regex style, I would use something like this in the API spec:

```
...    
paths:
    /docs/{document-id}:
        get:
          ...
    /docs/{document-id}(/section/{section-id))+:
        get:
          ...
```

So the questions are:

1. How do I represent arbitrarily nested resources in a Swagger/OpenAPI spec
2. Is there an alternative method that eliminates the need for recursive specification?

Comment: It's not supported currently. This issue looks related: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/892

Answer (score -4):

I'd recommend a simpler API design. In some companies, the limit is a maximum of 2 path parameters. Anything more and you're pushing the limit on usability.